# cmd не хочет устанавливать pip

Tags: python, cmd, pip

D:\Python>pip install Django
"pip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

[image: Вот]

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Нужно в переменные пути в PATH добавить путь к папке, где будет pip. Например, у меня два пути там: `C:\Users\IPetrash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37` и `C:\Users\IPetrash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts`. Первый для пути к python.exe, второй к pip.exe и прочим. После добавления в переменные пути нужно перезапустить консоль

Comment: Перед вызовом `pip` перейдите (`cd`) в директорию `Scripts`, которая находится в директории, в которую вы установили Python. `cd <Путь к Python>/Scripts`.